# How to select recursively in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
components
 id | number | name  | context | ...
-------------------------------------
 1  |  1234  | Test  |   car   | ...
 2  |  1235  | Test  |   car   | ...
 3  |  1236  | Test  |   car   | ...
 4. |  1237  | Test  |   car   | ...
... |   ...  | ...   |   car   | ...
_____________________________________
> 100.000 rows
```

```
boms
 id | parent | child | count
----------------------------
 1  |  1234  | 1235  |   1
 2  |  1234  | 1236  |   1
 3  |  1236  | 1237  |   2
... |   ...  | ...   |  ...
____________________________
> 500.000 rows
```

The purpose of these table is that `components` is a list of components with all the details related to that component. Table `boms` is a "Bill of material" that shows, which component is built into another component and how many times.

**Result as a tree:**

```
1234
  |-- 1x 1235
  |-- 1x 1236
           |-- 2x 1237
```

There are many components and many boms, as well as many contexts. How many is unknown and how many levels a BOM can have is unknown, as well.

As I don't know how to do the following at all, unfortunately, I can't provide any code snippet:

**TLTR:**

I want to provide a number and a context and receive a list of **all** components / children that the provided number in that context has. If context is not provided, the query must give me all children, no matter what the context is.

Here is a fiddle with my example data:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9599f911adb48563c789fa4fc513195d

Comment: [Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive)

Comment: *As I don't know how to do the following at all, unfortunately, I can't provide any code* Not a reason. CREATE TABLE for both tables, INSERT INTO with some sample data (5-7 rows enough) and desired output for this data can be made "by hands". Create and provide.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your feedback. I added a fiddle to my question.

Comment: (1) Does your MySQl version is really 5.7? (2) Provide desired output (as formatted table) for this data. (3) The same fiddle on another online fiddle which seems more useful for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9599f911adb48563c789fa4fc513195d

Comment: No it's not. Thank you. I added your link to my question

Comment: This is a fiddle which builds plain tree representation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=743af726814e1ea164487b2b812721c9 PS. CHAR(255) can be too short - expand if needed.

Comment: But this is taking "everything" and not all children of a given number, respecting a giving context

Comment: Modify WHERE in anchor subquery as needed simply, like ```WHERE `number` = 1234```, and you'll obtain the tree starting from needed number. WHERE EXISTS provides tree building from root nodes only.

Comment: Using `WHERE `number` = 1234 AND NOT EXISTS ...` is working but `WHERE `number` = 1236 AND NOT EXISTS ...` is not starting at this node

Comment: You must replace and remove NOT EXISTS condition, not add one more condition.

Comment: Yes, this is working but even without the entire `AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL FROM boms WHERE components.number = boms.child)` is working as well

Comment: I doubt... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b118928b042d19091de581446480c64d

Comment: My bad, do you want to add your query as an answer so that I can accept at. Would be more helpful for future reference. Anyhow: Thank you very much. Finally, that is the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fiddle which builds plain tree representation:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( 
    SELECT `number`, CAST(`number` AS CHAR(255)) path
    FROM components
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                       FROM boms
                       WHERE components.`number` = boms.child )
  UNION ALL
    SELECT boms.child, CONCAT(cte.path, '/', boms.child)
    FROM cte
    JOIN boms ON cte.`number` = boms.parent
)
SELECT `number`, components.name, components.context, boms.count, cte.path
FROM cte
JOIN components USING (`number`)
LEFT JOIN boms ON `number` = boms.child
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=743af726814e1ea164487b2b812721c9)

If you need the tree for one definite node then modify WHERE in anchor subquery, remove WHERE NOT EXISTS condition and add the condition which selects needed starting node, like `` WHERE `number` = 1234 ``.

PS. CHAR(255) can be too short - expand if needed.